# What are "processed dates", are they ready to eat or just easy to wash?

Tags: food-safety, fruit, dried-fruit

I got a package of dates, an oval long one, with an interesting-looking spoon/stick inside of the package along with dates. It is not stated on the package if they are ready to eat or not, but they are called processed dates. Strangely enough, google search results literally gave no useful information on the matter. The only difference I see between these dates and normal vacuum packed ones is that they are much easier to wash. Are they supposed to be ready to eat? If not, what is the purpose of that spoon thing?
Edit: This is a package that looks similar to the one I got (the one I got was almost identical, but it seems to be from a obscure firm): [image: dates with spoon]
I can't tell if this picture includes a ready to eat indication, but, just to reiterate, the package I refer to didn't say if they are ready to eat or not.

Comment: spoon might be to remove the seed if they aren't already de-seeded.

Comment: Picture would help this question. [Edit] to add one - the "sun and mountains" icon above the edit box. All the dates I've ever gotten (USA locale) were ready to eat as packed (assuming you can manage spitting out the pit if not pitted.)

Answer (score 1):

These are ready to eat, there's no need to wash them.

"Processed" means they're washed, dried, sorted, the ones with bugs removed, sometimes preservatives are added, they're rehydrated if too dry, etc.

The little plastic "branch" is intended to skewer them if you want to eat them without ending up with sticky fingers. However it is in the package with the dates, so the handle will be sticky with sugar anyway.